# Prevent postgres function of running more than 1 instance at the same time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, functions, cron

DBMS: Postgres 9.3.4
OS: Debian 7

I have a plpgsql function that will be put in crontab to run every 15 minutes. The function should finish in about 8 minutes, but just in case it takes more than 15 minutes, it CAN'T run until the last execution has finished.

I could think in more than 1 workaround, but I was wondering if there is some best known solution for this. Maybe something native on plpgsql syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the exclusion in the `cron` job definition. The handy `flock` shell command is intended for exactly this.

To do it inside PostgreSQL you would have the function take a lock that it holds for the duration of its run. Lots of options - `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`, do a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` of a particular row, or use `pg_advisory_xact_lock`. See the [explicit locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) chapter. The main advantage of using an advisory lock is that you don't need to create some table/row just to lock it in the case where there's no "natural" candidate for a lock target.

You can use the `try` forms of the advisory lock functions, or `NOWAIT` locks, if you want to abort a run instead of queueing it up. If you're using `psql` remember that by default it continues on error instead of aborting, so use `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1` in combination with `NOWAIT`.

Comment: Thanks for the `flock` command. Very handy. I guess it should be built into the function, though, to cover all vectors.

Comment: Used flock following this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169964/how-to-prevent-a-script-from-running-simultaneously and worked fine!